# shiny app hosted on shiny server displaying generic non-detailed error message instead of specific error message programmed by developer

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app, I have something like this:

```r
output$plot <- reactive({
  if (condition) {
     stop("very very detailed error message")
  }
})
```

When this shiny app is run locally, that is precisely the error message that will be outputed when `condition` is met.

However, this shiny app is also install on a remote shiny server. But on the shiny server, this is the error message:

```r
ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification
```

Comment: It's a good practice not to display detailed errors in apps that are in production. Have a look at [safeError](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/safeError.html)

Comment: stop is shown in console that's why you need to check the logs. if you want to see it in the webpage you need to implement a way to it. using `shinyjs::runjs("alert('very detailed message')")` instead of stop for example.